# RxJS - Loading indicator

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I'm struggling to get my head around the "Rx" way of displaying a loading indicator for an AJAX stream.

```
$scope.$createObservableFunction("load")
        .take(1)
        .do(function(){
            $scope.loading = true;
        })
        .flatMap(contentService.AJAX_THINGY_AS_OBSERVABLE)
        .delay(300)
        .subscribe(function(content){
            console.log("content",content);
        },function(error){
            $scope.error = error
        },function() {
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
```

As far as I understand it I should use `.do()` for side effects, which I suppose setting `loading` is, but it doesn't feel like the right way of doing things.

Can anyone provide a cleaner/better/proper example of how to do this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I decided to split this into 2 streams; `requestSource` and `responseSource`.

```
var loadRequestSource = $scope.$createObservableFunction("load")
    .share();

var loadResponseSource = loadRequestSource
    .flatMap(contentService.AJAX_THINGY_AS_OBSERVABLE)
    .throttle(1000)
    .share();
```

Then have 2 separate subscribers:

```
loadRequestSource.subscribe(function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
});

loadResponseSource.subscribe(function (response) {
    /* enter logic */
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.$digest();
}, function (err) {
    $scope.error = err;
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

I'm liking this approach as it keeps the role of the subscribes accurate. The response subscriber doesn't need to care about setting `loading` to `true`. It only cares about setting it to `false`.

Comment: lack of `$scope.$digest()` is not an issue in this case?

Comment: I later found out I needed it, yeah.

Comment: Anyway, you were asking about the concept, what is "the way" to do it. To be honest, I don't see more appropriate approach :P I would make it testable, ex. decouple logic from code that sets flags on `$scope`. But beside that, I don't know what you can do better.

Answer (score 2):

I like transforming the request/response streams into a single stream that represents the current state of your loading property:

```
const startLoading$ = loadRequestSource.map(() => true);
const stopLoading$ = loadResponseSource.map(() => false);
const loadingState$ = Rx.Observable.merge(startLoading$, stopLoading$);

// Finally, subscribe to the loadingState$ observable
loadingState$.subscribe(state => {
    $scope.$applyAsync(() => $scope.loading = state);
});
```